# how to get json data from framework (Yii)

Tags: android, json, yii, android-asynctask

i'm trying to get json data from website that i build using Yii framework.

when i open mozilla and i go to `http://localhost/restayii/index.php/employee/getemployee?id` it's showing employee json data.

this is my employee jsondata  :

```
{"employee":[{"id":"1","departmentId":"1","firstName":"Hendy","lastName":"Nugraha","gender":"female","birth_date":"1987-03-16","marital_status":"Single","phone":"856439112","address":"Tiban Mutiara View ","email":"hendy.nugraha87@yahoo.co.id","ext":"1","hireDate":"2012-06-30 00:00:00","leaveDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"2","departmentId":"2","firstName":"Jay","lastName":"Branham","gender":"male","birth_date":"0000-00-00","marital_status":"Single","phone":"0","address":"","email":"jaymbrnhm@labtech.org","ext":"2","hireDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","leaveDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"3","departmentId":"3","firstName":"Ahmad","lastName":"Fauzi","gender":"male","birth_date":"0000-00-00","marital_status":"Single","phone":"0","address":"","email":"ahmadfauzi@labtech.org","ext":"3","hireDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","leaveDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"4","departmentId":"1","firstName":"Henny","lastName":"Lidya Simanjuntak","gender":"female","birth_date":"1986-01-27","marital_status":"Married","phone":"2147483647","address":"Tiban Mutiara View ","email":"henokh_v@yahoo.com","ext":"1","hireDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","leaveDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"5","departmentId":"2","firstName":"sfg","lastName":"sfgsfg","gender":"male","birth_date":"2013-10-23","marital_status":"Single","phone":"356356","address":"sfgsfg","email":"sfgsfg","ext":"4","hireDate":"2012-05-30 00:00:00","leaveDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]}
```

this is on Android Activity.

Akses_Server_Aktivity :

```
public class Akses_Server_Activity extends Activity {

static String url ;
static final String Employee_ID = "id";
static final String Employee_Dept_ID = "departmentId";
static final String Employee_First_Name = "firstName";
static final String Employee_Last_Name = "lastName";
static final String Employee_Gender = "gender";
static final String Employee_Birth_Date = "birth_date";
static final String Employee_Marital_Status = "marital_status";
static final String Employee_Phone_Number = "phone";
static final String Employee_Address = "address";
static final String Employee_Email = "email";
static final String Employee_Ext = "ext";
static final String Employee_Hire_Date = "hireDate";
static final String Employee_Leave_Date = "leaveDate";
JSONArray employee = null;
JSONObject json_object;
Button callService;
EditText ip;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String get_ip;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.service_resta);

    ip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip_address);
    get_ip = ip.getText().toString();
    callService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_services);
    callService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                // masuk ke class Task
                new Task().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }  
    });
}

private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        // tampilkan progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Akses_Server_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            JSONParser json_parse = new JSONParser();

            url = "http://10.0.2.2/restayii/protected/controllers/EmployeeController.php";
            employee= json_parse.GetJson(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        // masuk ke method LoadEmployee()
        LoadEmployee();

    }
}

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    // Constructor
    public JSONParser(){

    }

    public JSONObject GetJson(String url) {

        // masuk ke class myasyntask
        new MyAsynTask().execute();
        return jObj;

    }

    public class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray Result){
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                jObj = new JSONArray(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void LoadEmployee(){
    try {
        employee = json_object.getJSONArray("employee");

        TableLayout table_layout =(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
        table_layout.removeAllViews();
        int jml_baris = employee.length();
        String [][] data_employee = new String [jml_baris][13];
        for(int i=0;i<jml_baris;i++){
            JSONObject Result = employee.getJSONObject(i);
            data_employee[i][0] = Result.getString(Employee_ID);
            data_employee[i][1] = Result.getString(Employee_Dept_ID);
            data_employee[i][2] = Result.getString(Employee_First_Name);
            data_employee[i][3] = Result.getString(Employee_Last_Name);
            data_employee[i][4] = Result.getString(Employee_Gender);
            data_employee[i][5] = Result.getString(Employee_Birth_Date);
            data_employee[i][6] = Result.getString(Employee_Marital_Status);
            data_employee[i][7] = Result.getString(Employee_Phone_Number);
            data_employee[i][8] = Result.getString(Employee_Address);
            data_employee[i][9] = Result.getString(Employee_Email);
            data_employee[i][10] = Result.getString(Employee_Ext);
            data_employee[i][11] = Result.getString(Employee_Hire_Date);
            data_employee[i][12] = Result.getString(Employee_Leave_Date);
        }

        TableLayout.LayoutParams ParameterTableLayout = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for(int j=0; j<jml_baris; j++){  
            TableRow  table_row = new TableRow(null);  
            table_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  
            table_row.setLayoutParams(ParameterTableLayout);  
            TableRow.LayoutParams ParameterTableRow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
            ParameterTableRow.setMargins(1,1,1,1);
            for(int kolom = 0; kolom < 13; kolom++){
                TextView TV= new TextView(null);
                TV.setText(data_employee[j][kolom]);  
                TV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);  
                TV.setPadding(1, 4, 1, 4);  
                TV.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  
                TV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
                table_row.addView(TV,ParameterTableRow);  
            }   
            table_layout.addView(table_row); 
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}

(On Android)

**The problem is:**

when this app launch, and i clicked button refresh, it's not showing table row that contains employee json data. but there's no error too on the logcat. Is it wrong with my url on class Task extends AsyncTask `http://10.0.2.2/restayii/protected/controllers/EmployeeController.php` ??

or should i replaced it with the same link just when i open it from mozilla `http://localhost/restayii/index.php/employee/getemployee?id`??

Edit:

I already change the url to `http://localhost/restayii/index.php/employee/getemployee?id` inside Task Class extends AsyncTask, but is still won't get employee json data from localhost.

please, Any help would be greatly apreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already find an answer. my problem is in sub class Task extends asyntask and also in jsonParser sub class.

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, JSONObject>{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        try {
            JSONParser json_parser = new JSONParser();
            json_object = json_parser.getJson(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json_object;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
        LoadEmployee(result);
    }
}

private class JSONParser {
    .....
    public JSONObject getJson(String url) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer hasil = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                hasil.append(line);
            }
            json = hasil.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

now i can get all json data from my Yii web service. hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know that, you have to refresh android screen when you called an ajax data...
May be this will show you the way...

Comment: can you be more spesific? i'm still new in this android programming

Comment: Me too :) But i tried to get json data on phonegap android app. i saw that i can see the data if page loaded at thee first time. then when i refresh the data, there is no error but i couldnt see the data. after searching the problem on google, I found a comment about this problem. It says that you hove to refresh screen if you called ajax data...

Comment: sorry for late reply. so what code that i should add to this app, to make it refresh?? i already change the url, but still not showing any json data on table row. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now you use wrong URL in the AsyncTask. The right URL is something like `http://localhost/restayii/index.php/employee/getemployee?id`

Comment: i already change the url to `http://localhost/restayii/index.php/employee/getemployee?id` on class Task extends Asynctask (in doInBackground) but it still not showing the employee json data